# my table view is created but array is not showing in table view,in console all the data are coming.please help me to solve json parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, uitableview

This is an response and I want to print this response values into the table view:
I am posting my tableview code please check is it right or wrong.
I am struggling over here for 2 days if any one know please reply me.

```
 - (IBAction)search:(UIButton *)sender {


NSString *post =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"keyword=%@",[keyword text]];
NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
//[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

//NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSError *error=nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (!urlData) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    //return NO;
}


NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);



if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
 {
    NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSLog(@"json ==> %@ ", dic);
    name     = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    username = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (id obj in dic) {
        NSString *nameNameObj=[obj objectForKey:@"name"];
        [name  addObject:nameNameObj];
         NSString *userNameObj=[obj objectForKey:@"username"];
        [username  addObject:userNameObj];

    }

    NSLog(@"name array is %@",name);
    NSLog(@"username array is %@",username);

  }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
   // Return the number of sections.
    return [name count];
    return 1;
 }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
  {
    return [name count];
  }
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  
  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
  {
   static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MYCustomCell";
   MyCustomCellTableViewCell *cell = (MyCustomCellTableViewCell *)
   [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil)
    {
     NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]    
     loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCellTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
     cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    // apply setters for cell
    cell.nameLbl.text=[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.usernameLbl.text=[username objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
 }
[
    {"id":60,"username":"test001","name":"name"},     
    {"id":61,"username":"test","name":""},  
    {"id":65,"username":"test002","name":"first"},
    {"id":69,"username":"test003","name":"second"}, 
    {"id":71,"username":"test004","name":"third"},
    {"id":78,"username":"test005","name":"fourth"},
    {"id":79,"username":"test006","name":"Name of the person"}
]
```

Comment: Please add your tableview delegate methods here. Without that we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IGNORE THIS, AS YOU ARE NOT USING THIS**

Check this 2 lines:

```
cell.nameLbl.text = [name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.usernameLbl.text = [username objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

`name` is an array, that contains a NSDictionary in each index. So if you want to access its values you have to do this:

```
cell.nameLbl.text = [[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.usernameLbl.text = [[username objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"username"]];
```

**EDIT:**

As you've edited your code, the modified answer will be :

```
 - (IBAction)search:(UIButton *)sender {


    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"keyword=%@",[keyword text]];
    NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

    ......
    ......

    if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
    {
        NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);
        .....
        .....

        for (id obj in dic) {
            NSString *nameNameObj=[obj objectForKey:@"name"];
            [name  addObject:nameNameObj];
            NSString *userNameObj=[obj objectForKey:@"username"];
            [username  addObject:userNameObj];

        }

        .......
        .......
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
}
```

Comment: no its not working. again data is coming in console but not shown in table view..

Comment: @ParveshMishra > Do your name and username array has data?

Comment: 2016-03-02 15:38:23.107 UITableView1[7722:105442] name array is (
    vfvv,
    "",
    "",
    "Ben Franklin",
    vneflv,
    "Ben Franklin",
    "Name of the person"
)
2016-03-02 15:38:23.108 UITableView1[7722:105442] username array is (
    test001,
    test,
    test002,
    test003,
    test004,
    test005,
    test006
)

Comment: cell.nameLbl.text =@"Test Text"; check if you can see this.

Comment: So you can see the problem is not here. Problem is somewhere else.

Comment: i can send my project if u can help me.!

Comment: You can upload it dropbox/google drive and give me the link, I'll try to look at it.

Comment: You have a lot of mistakes. I am sorry I don't have that much time, but here is the working copy. Please study about iOS first. http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=04335622166896879952

Answer (score 0):

There might be some of the reason below:

1. Make sure you set Delegate and Datasource correctly.
2. When you receive response reload tableView on main thread

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{                                                                  

         [self.tableView reloadData];
   });
   ```
3. Return valid cell from

   ```
   cellForRowAtIndexPath:
   ```
4. Return valid number of cell from

   ```
   numberOfRowInSection:
   ```